# Should initials of names be seperated by a dot or by a hyphen for seo purposes

Tags: seo, url

I wanted to use names with initials in the URL. For example if j.k. Brothers is the initials and name then is it good to make my URL like so:

```
sitename.com/j.k.brothers/listing/
```

Or would it be better to use hyphens like so:

```
sitename.com/j-k-brothers/listing/
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

While Google and other search engines will most likely understand either its generally best to use [hyphens as these are classed as word separators](http://www.mattcutts.com/blog/dashes-vs-underscores/). Fullstops or dots are generally associated with determining file types.. For example .html .php .xml .rar .zip and so on.

My personal advice would to be use hyphens over the usage of underscores and dots in URL formats.